# How to set up web.config for CakePHP 2.6 on windows server?

Tags: php, cakephp, mod-rewrite, iis-7, cakephp-2.6

I want to setup cakephp website on windows server and I have checked that URL Rewrite module is installed.

As suggested [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html#url-rewrites-on-iis7-windows-hosts), IIS7 does not natively support .htaccess files. While there are add-ons that can add this support, you can also import htaccess rules into IIS to use CakePHP’s native rewrites. I have followed the instructions given [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html#url-rewrites-on-iis7-windows-hosts).

I have put the web.config content given on cakephp website to the root folder of cakephp but when I run website, only home page is running properly and when I click on other links, it shows the home page only it is not redirecting to any other link.

Can anyone suggest, how to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.